# Unable to read files with PHP - XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp, file-get-contents

I generally work with WAMP but for some reason had to switch over to XAMPP.

Ran into this really weird problem. When i try to read a file using file_get_contents i get an error saying that the file/dir does not exist EVEN THOUGH IT DOES.

Even if something as simple as

```
file_get_contents('x.txt');
```

throws an error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(x.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\cryy\index.php on line 3
```

And yes, i've tried using the magic constant

> __DIR__

to no avail.

I'm using XAMPP 3.2.2 and PHP 7.0.18, running on Windows 10.

I hope someone can help me figure this out.

Comment: Where is your file? where is the file that execute this code?

Comment: try once with providing the full path of that file which you want to read

Comment: Your code is in `C:\xampp\htdocs\cryy\index.php` so the file is also in `C:\xampp\htdocs\cryy\` RIGHT???

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes

Answer (score 1):

Try providing full path of the you want to get content. If you want to access file from root of the folder, then you can use

```
file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."project_folder".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."filename.txt");
```

OR

```
file_get_contents(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."filename.txt");
```